# How to get the selected image in parent in <lightning-carousel>

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, onclickjavascript

I have a requirement where on click of `lightning-carousel` dots, we need to get the `lightning-carousel-image` that got clicked and we need to process the logic based on the selected image. Here I need to have `onclick` event on `lightning-carousel` only and not on `lightning-carousel-image`

[image]

Eg: LWC component

```
<lightning-carousel disable-auto-scroll onclick= {findClickedElement}>
    <lightning-carousel-image
        header={First Card}
        description="First card description." 
        data-name="First Card">      
    </lightning-carousel-image>
    <lightning-carousel-image
        header={Second Card}
        description="Second card description."
        data-name="Second Card">
    </lightning-carousel-image>
    <lightning-carousel-image
        header={Third card description.}
        description="three"
        data-name="Third Card">
    </lightning-carousel-image>
```

LWCJs:

```
export default class lwcClassJs extends LightningElement {
   findClickedElement(event){
      let element = this.template.querySelector("lightning-carousel");
      console.log('@@element-->'+element);
      //Here I am not able to get the <lightning-carousel-image> that is clicked in UI. 
   }
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to get the `lightning-carousel-image` that is displayed on the click of dot?

Comment: Do you want to perform logic when the dot is clicked or when the image is clicked?

Comment: @GargiGupta I want to perform the logic on click of dot. For that I wanted to know which image is getting displayed on click of dot